# set Brave as default browser in DoomEmacs

Tags: doom, web-browser

I am new to DoomEmacs, I am on Ubuntu and I want to set Brave as my default web browser. How can I do this?

Currently Chrome is set to this but I do not know how to change it.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, Emacs use system default browser (i.e. the value of `browse-url-browser-function` is `browse-url-default-browser`).

Though there are many choices of `browse-url-browser-function` (e.g. `browse-url-firefox`, `browse-url-chrome` and `browse-url-kde`), there is not `browse-url-brave`.

There are same choices can achieve you need:

1. set Brave as your system default browser

or

2. **I'm not sure whether the name of the browser program used by Brave is `brave`, correct it by yourself.**

```lisp
(setq browse-url-browser-function 'browse-url-generic
      browse-url-generic-program "brave")
```